# Are these two methods of transforming probability distributions the same?

Tags: real-analysis, probability, analysis, probability-theory, probability-distributions

If one has a probability distribution $p_X(x)$ on some subset $X\subset \mathbb R^n$ and a smooth function $f:X\to\mathbb R$, one way to find $p_f(y)$ would be via:
$$p_f(y)=\int_X dx\ p_f(y\mid x)p(x)=\int_X dx\ \delta(y-f(x))p(x)=\int_{f^{-1}(y)}dx\,\frac1{\|\nabla f(x)\|}p(x)$$
Wikipedia presents another [method](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Probability/Transformation_of_Probability_Densities#General_Problem_and_Solution_.28n-to-m_mapping.29), which also seems "obviously true":
$$p_f(y)=\partial_y \int_{f(x)≤y} dx\, p(x)$$

Are these two methods actually equivalent? They seem to be (at least superficially) really different expressions.

Comment: Can't $f^{-1}(y)$ have zero measure?

Comment: I'm not sure anymore, the first expression doesn't make sense to me right now. In my defence I was still a physicist when I wrote this question. Anyway it seems like $f^{-1}(y)$ should be something like a sub-manifold on which one has a natural induced meausre (induced by the restriction of the euclidean metric). For example with $f(x)=2x$  you have $f^{-1}(y)$ is just one point which should have measure $1$ (despite being a nullset of the usual Lebesgue measure), the above formula will then give the correct transformation of the density under the function $f$.

Comment: ha! glad you healed yourself. thanks for the more info